# WordML: Set Table Cell Width

Tags: wordml

How are cell widths set in WordML?
I tried the w:w attribute of the w:tcW tag, but it has no effect.
I want to set cell widths independantly of the column.
I also want a different number of cells on each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use  `<w:tblGrid>` if you want to set the cell width irrespective of the column width check [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2009/11/05/comparison-of-html-css-tables-to-wordprocessingml-tables.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The `tcW` element has one more optional attribute: `w:type` , that determines the measure of the width. The default seems to be `auto`. Try to set it to another measure, such as `dxa`,`in`, or `pct`.